# no match for "operator<<" (operand types are 'std::ostream'

Tags: c++

In this program, I get the following error:

```
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >')
```

referring to the cout << count in the following code.  I'm pretty new to c++ and unsure how to fix this.  I looked over other examples similar to my error and none looked relational to mine.  How do I fix this error?  I'm guessing it has something to do with vector::size_type and vector.end() type auto conversion to count and not being able to convert to char or string, but how do I address this?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ostream &print(ostream &os, const vector<string> &vs)
{
    for(const auto &i: vs)
      os << i << " ";
    return os;
}

string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string &word, const string &ending = "s") {
     return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}

// if list used instead, no need for erase since it is default called unique
// member call
void elimDups(vector<string> &words)
{
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end());
    words.erase(end_unique, words.end());
    print(cout, words);
}

void biggies(vector<string> &words, vector<string>::size_type sz)
{
    elimDups(words); // alphabetize words order and remove dups
    // sort words by size and alphabetize same size
    stable_sort(words.begin(), words.end(), 
      [] (const string &a, const string &b)
          { return a.size() < b.size();});
// get an iterator to the first element whose size() is >= sz
    auto wc = find_if(words.begin(), words.end(), [sz] (const string &a)
       { return a.size() >= sz; });
    auto count = words.end() - sz;
    cout << count << " "
         << make_plural(count, "word", "s")
         << " of length " << sz
         << " or longer" << endl;
         // print words of the given size or longer, each one followed by a space
    for_each(wc, words.end(), [] (const string &s)
       { cout << s << " ";});
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> vs2{"fox", "the", "jumps", "over", 
      "quick", "red", "slow", "red", "turtle"}

    elimDups(vs);
    elimDups(vs2);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `auto count = words.end() - wc;`, not `sz`, although using `distance` may be a better idea.

Comment: Well what do you know?  Apart from a couple of other minor typos,  [he's right](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nd85UmNtk0X4qxoY). Go go go, @Retired.

Answer (score 4):

The statement in function `void biggies(vector<string> &words, vector<string>::size_type sz)` on line number 38

```
auto count = words.end() - sz;
```

The part `words.end()` gives you an iterator and then you are subtracting a scalar which again gives you an iterator.

So the variable `count` is a iterator and the operator `<<` is not defined for iterator.

What you can do is:

```
 auto count = words.size() - sz; // a number;
```

or

```
auto count = words.end() - wc; // a number;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Simple fix, appreciate it.

Comment: Another example showing `auto` is not the 'Holy Grail' it is often presented as... `size_t count = ...` would have made the error obvious right in the line it occurred. Not advocating against auto, but one needs to be aware it cannot be used *carelessly*...